# How to add js code to HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Hello my goal is to login to page.aspx change all ddl options that change data and save it all.
I can save only first data.I tried this in console log and it works

```
$("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_AccountsDDL_ddlAccounts")[0].selectedIndex = 0;
$("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_AccountsDDL_ddlAccounts").change();
location.reload();
```

So now I just need to pass this data to my PostString or to run this some how.
And here I am stuck. So any ideas how I can insert this 3 line in my PostString/HttpWebRequest ?

This my code

```
HttpWebRequest postRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.com/Pages/current.aspx");
PostString += "ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$AccountsDDL$ddlAccounts=" + Number + "&";//Here
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(PostString);
postRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
Stream newStream = postRequest.GetRequestStream();
newStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
newStream.Close();
HttpWebResponse postResponse = (HttpWebResponse)postRequest.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 0):

Those 3 likes of code are Javascript. They run on a Javascript engine contained on the browser. In your case, you are making the request programatically, which means the client is your application, there are no browsers involved. So, unless you find a way to involve a Javascript  engine functionality, the Javascript code won't be run.

I think your best chance is to send some GET/POST variables that would trigger the desired behavior on the page. That would required additional implementation on the specific page.

Comment: This is what i trying to do,but i can't find the way